# MySql tinyint confusing working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select, with inactive column, which is tinyint

```
SELECT
test_case.caseid AS caseid,
test_case.inactive AS inactive
from test_case
WHERE test_case.inactive = "{inactive_value}"
```

If the inactive_value "0", or "1", works as expected, but if I write "str", then the result won't be empty. In the result will be all, or at least the inactive = "0"

Why this is happenind with this SQl select?

DDL relevant part:

```
inactive tinyint default '0' not null
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and table structure.

Comment: `str`, being purely alphanumeric, is helpfully (or otherwise) implicitly converted to `0` before the comparison.

Comment: If implicitly converted to 0, then to "1" should not work.
I want to get empty list, if I select with dummy datas, and this case in the result I got almost everything, which seems buggy.
Relevant part of table structure: inactive tinyint default '0' not null,

Comment: @BenjáminGerván The string is converted to a number. If the string begins with a number it gets converted to that number. A string that doesn't begin with a number is converted to `0`.

Comment: That makes a little sense, but I'm not happy with it :) thank you the answers